# Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having trouble with a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. The stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UPLOAD_MOVTIT_Update]
( @IN_ID_RECORD             nvarchar(2)
, @IN_COD_IST               nvarchar(5)
, @IN_COD_SOC_GEST          char(5)
, @IN_COD_PTF               nvarchar(2)
, @IN_COD_LIN               nvarchar(2)
, @IN_COD_GEST              nvarchar(5)
, @IN_DAT_RIF               nvarchar(10)    
, @IN_DAT_VAL               nvarchar(10)
, @IN_ID_UPLOAD             nvarchar(2)
, @IN_COD_CAUS              nvarchar(6)
, @IN_VAL_COD_TIT           nvarchar(30)
, @IN_DIV_RIF               nvarchar(3)
, @IN_IMP                   numeric(25,3)
, @IN_IMP_RATEO             decimal(18,3)
, @IN_QTA                   numeric(18,5)
, @IN_PRZ                   decimal(21, 10) = 0
, @IN_FX                    decimal(18, 9)
, @IN_COD_MER               nvarchar(20)
, @IN_NOTE                  nvarchar(100))

AS      

DECLARE @@SQL                   nvarchar(max)
    , @@TABLE_NAME              nvarchar(45)
    , @@WHERE                   nvarchar(max)
    , @@DAT_RIF                 smalldatetime   
    , @@DAT_VAL                 smalldatetime

SET NOCOUNT ON   

SET @@TABLE_NAME = 'UPLOAD_MOVTIT'
SET @@TABLE_NAME = @@TABLE_NAME + '_' + @IN_COD_SOC_GEST 

SET @@WHERE = ' WHERE'

IF (LTRIM(@IN_ID_RECORD) <> '')
    SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND ID_RECORD = '+@IN_ID_RECORD

IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_IST) <> '')       
    SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_IST = @IN_COD_IST'

IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_SOC_GEST) <> '')
    SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_SOC_GEST = @IN_COD_SOC_GEST'  

--IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_PTF) <> '')
--  SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_PTF = @IN_COD_PTF'    

--IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_LIN) <> '')     
--  SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_LIN = @IN_COD_LIN'

--IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_GEST) <> '')        
--  SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_GEST = @IN_COD_GEST'  

IF (LTRIM(@IN_DAT_RIF) <> '')
    SET @@DAT_RIF = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, LTRIM(@IN_DAT_RIF), 103) 

IF (LTRIM(@IN_DAT_VAL) <> '')
    SET @@DAT_VAL = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, LTRIM(@IN_DAT_VAL), 103) 

IF (LTRIM(@IN_ID_UPLOAD) <> '')
    SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND ID_UPLOAD = '+@IN_ID_UPLOAD   

IF (@@WHERE <> ' WHERE')        
    SET @@WHERE = REPLACE(@@WHERE, ' WHERE AND', ' WHERE')
ELSE
    SET @@WHERE = ''

BEGIN
    SET @@SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @@TABLE_NAME 
        + ' SET COD_PTF = @IN_COD_PTF
            , COD_LIN = @IN_COD_LIN
            , COD_GEST = @IN_COD_GEST
            , DAT_RIF = '+@@DAT_RIF+' 
            , DAT_VAL = '+@@DAT_VAL+'
            , COD_CAUS = @IN_COD_CAUS
            , VAL_COD_TIT = @IN_VAL_COD_TIT
            , DIV_RIF = @IN_DIV_RIF
            , IMP = @IN_IMP
            , IMP_RATEO = @IN_IMP_RATEO
            , QTA = @IN_QTA
            , PRZ = @IN_PRZ
            , FX = @IN_FX
            , COD_MER = @IN_COD_MER
            , NOTE = @IN_NOTE
            , DAT_ULT_MOD = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ' + @@WHERE 

END

PRINT @@sql

EXEC sp_executesql @@SQL


, N'@IN_ID_RECORD nvarchar(2), @IN_COD_IST  nvarchar(5), @IN_COD_SOC_GEST char(5), @IN_COD_PTF nvarchar(2), @IN_COD_LIN nvarchar(2), @IN_COD_GEST nvarchar(5), @IN_DAT_RIF nvarchar(10), @IN_DAT_VAL nvarchar(10), @IN_COD_CAUS nvarchar(6), @IN_VAL_COD_TIT nvarchar(30), @IN_DIV_RIF  nvarchar(3), @IN_ID_UPLOAD nvarchar(2), @IN_IMP numeric(25,3), @IN_IMP_RATEO decimal(18,3), @IN_QTA numeric(18,5), @IN_PRZ  decimal(21, 10), @IN_FX decimal(18, 9), @IN_COD_MER nvarchar(20), @IN_NOTE nvarchar(100)'
                        , @IN_ID_RECORD, @IN_COD_IST, @IN_COD_SOC_GEST, @IN_COD_PTF, @IN_COD_LIN, @IN_COD_GEST, @IN_DAT_RIF, @IN_DAT_VAL, @IN_COD_CAUS, @IN_VAL_COD_TIT, @IN_DIV_RIF, @IN_ID_UPLOAD, @IN_IMP, @IN_IMP_RATEO, @IN_QTA, @IN_PRZ, @IN_FX, @IN_COD_MER, @IN_NOTE



RETURN @@ERROR
```

The error message is the following:

> Msg 295, Level 16, State 3, Procedure sp_UPLOAD_MOVTIT_Update, Line 91
>   Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.

At first I thought the error was on those lines:

```
SET @@DAT_RIF = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, LTRIM(@IN_DAT_RIF), 103)
```

But after some debugging, I saw that it is on those lines:

```
            , DAT_RIF = '+@@DAT_RIF+' 
            , DAT_VAL = '+@@DAT_VAL+'
```

because by design the table where the update has to be done has those two columns set to `smalldatetime` and the stored procedure is casting those two variables to string when it builds the query.

Anyone knows how to get around this error?

EDIT: This is the test case I'm trying to use and returns the error:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_UPLOAD_MOVTIT_Update]
        @IN_ID_RECORD = N'44',
        @IN_COD_IST = N'0',
        @IN_COD_SOC_GEST = N'90000',
        @IN_COD_PTF = N'20',
        @IN_COD_LIN = N'22',
        @IN_COD_GEST = N'00222',
        @IN_DAT_RIF = N'14/06/2017',
        @IN_DAT_VAL = N'18/04/2017',
        @IN_ID_UPLOAD = N'37',
        @IN_COD_CAUS = N'S',
        @IN_VAL_COD_TIT = N'IE00B1W4R501',
        @IN_DIV_RIF = N'USD',
        @IN_IMP = 1022924.19,
        @IN_IMP_RATEO = 0.00,
        @IN_QTA = 66000.00,
        @IN_PRZ = 15.50,
        @IN_FX = 1.07,
        @IN_COD_MER = N' ',
        @IN_NOTE = N' '

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: Using dynamic SQL like this leaves you fully exposed to SQL injection attacks and conversion problems, like the one you just encountered. You get no benefit at all by writing dynamic sql inside the stored procedure.

Comment: As for the immediate problem, use the proper type for each parameter. Data parameters should have a date type, eg `date` or `datatime2`, *not* varchar*. `smalldatatime` is deprecated anyway and doesn't offer any benefits over eg `date` or `datetime2(0)`. The same holds for *integer* or *decimal* parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ISDATE()** Function To check the string is valid date Or Not

Ref Link [ISDATE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql)

Put Case When

```
Case when Isdate(@Datevar)=1 then convert(date, @datrevar) else '' end
```

Comment: Better yet, just *don't* pass dates as strings. The string may have any date format, `ISDATE` and `CONVERT` can fail *very* easily if the format doesn't match the server's locale. Worse, they can produce bad data. What is 4/7? July 4 or April 7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the variables after this line of the statement: `sp_executesql @@SQL`

And write:

```
            , DAT_RIF = @@DAT_RIF 
            , DAT_VAL = @@DAT_VAL
```